# What does CloudQueue.EndAddMessage(IAsyncResult) actually do?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

Let's say I call

```
AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(QueueMessageAdded);
queue.BeginAddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage(message), callback, null);
```

where `QueueMessageAdded` is

```
private static void QueueMessageAdded(IAsyncResult result)
{
    queue.EndAddMessage(result);
}
```

What does **EndAddMessage** do?

Including waiting for all callbacks to have been called, it is as slow as calling the synchronous version like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(messages, message => queue.AddMessage(message));
```

Answer (score 1):

First approach makes the request asynchronously and therefore your thread does not have to block while waiting for a response. Second approach, on the other hand, will use N threads, each of which will block until a response is received to its respective request.

Please refer to [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228963.aspx) for more information. All End* methods complete the asynchronous operation, meaning it will block until the operation finishes, return the operation's result if any, and do clean-up.

Comment: The second approach (Parallel) won't create threads; it will merely acquisition them from the thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach allow you to use *concurrent* requests! A single thread, can, with the first approach send hundreds of concurrent messages, even though the latency of a single POST request to get its reply is high. If you look at [production code targeting ASB](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit-AzureServiceBus/blob/master/src/MassTransit.Transports.AzureServiceBus.Receiver/Receiver.fs) you can see some patterns in how APM/Async is used.

Comment: Thank you, that was not my primary question though - sorry if that was unclear. I still wonder what the function EndAddMessage does and if/why it's necessary to call it.